# Why wont this display in IE8?

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, stylesheet

```
    <div style="width:180px; height:18px; border-bottom:1px solid #666; position:relative; z-index:500; margin-left:10px;">
        <div style="float:left; width:70px; height:18px; position:absolute; left:0; top:0; z-index:1; background-color:white; ">KEY</div>
        <div style="float:right; height:18px; position:absolute; right:0; top:0; z-index:1; background-color:white; ">VALUE</div>
    </div>
```

Renders perfectly in Chrome, Firefox, Safari, etc. But in IE8 it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE8 is a jerk with relative positioning if the renderer doesn't detect the doctype properly.  Try specifying:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```